does /etc/passwd primary group mean you are in that group?
This is in RHEL-8.10 for what it's worth...
in /etc/passwd I have
ron:x:20000:100:me:/home/ron:/bin/bash

so my uid is 20000, and my gid is 100 which as defined by convention in /etc/group is the users group.  And after a clean install of Linux from iso the users group in /etc/group is empty.
The scenario is this:
mkdir /data
chown jack.users /data
chmod 770 /data


ls -l /data shows  drwxrwx---.  4  jack  users <date>  data
account ron is not in users:x:100: in /etc/group.
as /ron cannot cd /data with it as drwxrwx---.

ron can only cd /data if

chmod 777 /data or
putronin/etc/groupunderusers:x:100:ron`





Can someone let me know what I may be missing or doing wrong which would contribute to such a scenario?
The baffling part is I have a RHEL-8.10 server with some hundred users defined in /etc/passwd all having their primary group id as 100 and none are defined in users:x:100: in /etc/group and this problem does not happen.
Does your account primary group in /etc/passwd mean that you are inherently in that group or do you also need to also list those accounts in /etc/group after users:x:100: ?

what do you get if you log in as ron and run id?

This question is similar to: Why don't /etc/group and /etc/password match?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're inherently in the primary group set via the gid in /etc/passwd. That gid doesn't even have to exist in /etc/group (or any other sources of groups, such as LDAP)

Also note the dot at the end of the permission characters, indicating a SELinux security context, which might affect access to the directory.

@muru - no that similar question is different.   It seems to state what it means which I don't disagree with, but I am experiencing what seems to be a contradiction.

When you say, clean install, you mean an actual clean install, right? No additional software installed, no company or other organisational configuration done, etc.? You could reproduce this on a Docker container, for example?

to clarify - /etc/passwd with ron:x:20000:100 I can delete users:x:100: from /etc/groupand then any folder **not owned** by me {ron} but having a gid 100 I cancdto it with it beingdrwxrwx---` ?  This is basically my question here.

clean install = download rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso from redhat, put to usb stick, F11 boot manager install from usb, server with gui and less than 5 other options in that install gui

The primary group is defined in /etc/passwd.  Secondary group membership is assigned in /etc/group.  Users with primary groups defined do not need to have entries in those same groups in the /etc/group file.
The primary group is used for the default when creating files and directories.  Secondary groups can be assigned to files/directories if the user is a member as defined in /etc/group.
As for your "ron" question, what group(s) is he in?  If his primary group is not 100, then it won't match your group access by default.  But, if he were in the /etc/group file in the "users" group, then he would.  If he is not listed in a matching group in /etc/group and his primary GID is different than yours, then you will need to either open the directory up to the "world" (777) or assign ron to "users" in /etc/group.
The behavior you are seeing appears to be exactly what's expected in all unix's.
PS.  Don't delete "users" from /etc/group even if there are no users assigned to it.  The system still uses /etc/group as a cross-reference for primary GID name resolution.
If you delete "users:x:100:" from /etc/group, when you do an "ls -l" (for example) you will not see the group name; instead, you will see the GID number.
